# Show by combinatorial argument that ${2n\choose 2} = 2{n \choose 2} + n^2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

So i was given this question. Show by combinatorial argument that ${2n\choose 2} = 2{n \choose 2} + n^2$

Here is my solution:

Given $2n$ objects, split them into $2$ groups of $n$, $A$ and $B$. $2$-combinations can either be assembled both from $A$, both from $B$ or one from each. There are ${n \choose 2}$ from $A$ and ${n \choose 2}$ from $B$. For the mixed pair, each choice from $A$ can be coupled with $n$ choices from $B$ so the total is $n^2$.

Therefore ${2n\choose 2} = 2{n \choose 2} + n^2$

Is this correct. Is there any other combinatoric proof to solve this?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Yes, correct. And, no, any other combinatorical proof would have to be way too weird

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: "For the mixed pair, each choice from $A$ can be coupled with $n$ choices from $B$ so the total is $n^2$." What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a generalization of this fact that I cannot resist sharing. Here is how I came across it: Consider the scenario where you keep additively splitting a positive integer into two positive integers as a tree diagram, until you are left with only $1$'s as the leaves. Then you take the product of the two numbers at each branching and sum all such products. Remarkably, applying this process to $n$ will always yield $\binom{n}{2}$ as the final number. Try it with $8$ and you get $28$ every time. The inductive step of the strong induction argument for this fact uses the fact that, if you split $n=a+b$ then $$\binom{a}{2}+\binom{b}{2}+ab=\binom{a+b}{2}=\binom{n}{2}.$$ A combinatorial proof double counts the number of ways of choosing two people out of $n=a+b$ people. We can either choose $2$ out of the $a$ or $2$ out of the $b$ or $1$ from each. The original post asks for a combinatorial proof of this fact when $a=b.$

Comment: Have you seen the visual proof of this? It's delightful in its own right...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I haven't seen it. Do you have a reference or link?

Comment: I've seen it on other posts here but I can't recall a good specific one. I can hopefully describe it: draw the usual right-angled $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ 'grid triangle' with $n\choose 2$ squares in it (i.e., all unit squares around vertices $\langle i,j\rangle$ with $1\leq i,j$ and $i+j\leq n$). Then points on the diagonal of this triangle correspond to partitions $n=a+b$; the subdivision ${n\choose 2}={a\choose 2}+{b\choose 2}+ab$ corresponds to breaking the original triangle into the $a\times b$ rectangle from that point to the origin and two smaller square right triangles.

Comment: The 'game' of splitting up the number and taking products corresponds to repeatedly chewing off maximally-large rectangular chunks from one of the remaining grid triangles.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That's really nice. Took me a moment to visualize, but I got it. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to think about it:

Let's find the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{2n}$. On one side, it's equal to ${2n}\choose2$. On the other hand, it's equal to the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n$ which is equal to the sum of products of coefficients of $x^0$ and $x^2$, $x^1$ and $x^1$, and $x^2$ and $x^0$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$. That's equal to ${n\choose2}\cdot{ n\choose0}+{n\choose1}\cdot{ n\choose1}+{n\choose0}\cdot{ n\choose2}$ and the result follows.

Comment: One might as well simply notice that both sides equal $2n^2 - n$.

Answer (score -1):

Theorem: C(2n, 2) = 2C(n, 2) + n^2

Proof.

Suppose we have 2 groups, both of size n, which combine to make a class of size 2n, and we wish to know the number of ways we can choose 2 members from the class.  This is represented by C(2n, 2).

There are C(n, 2) ways we can choose 2 students from a single group. Since there are 2 groups, there are 2C(n, 2) ways we can choose 2 students from a single group.  Finally, there are n^2 ways to choose to members from the class where each member is from a different group, so there are 2C(n, 2) + n^2 ways to choose 2 members from the class of size 2n.

Therefore C(2n, 2) = 2C(n, 2) + n^2∎

Comment: Did you read the question? This proof is already contained in the question.

Answer (score -2):

A more direct (and, in my opinion, simple) approach is to expand and simplify until both sides are equivalent.

$${{2n}\choose{2}}=2{{n}\choose{2}}+n^2$$

First, expand both sides using ${{n}\choose{k}}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2!(2n-2)!}=2\left[{\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}}\right]+n^2$$

Expand again, this time focusing on the factorials:

$$\frac{(1)(2)(3)...(2n-2)(2n-1)(2n)}{(1)(2)*(1)(2)(3)...(2n-2)}=2\left[\frac{(1)(2)(3)...(n-2)(n-1)(n)}{(1)(2)*(1)(2)(3)...(n-2)}\right]+n^2$$

In this format, it's easy to see that some variables of the factorials on each side cancel each other out:

$$\frac{(2n-1)(2n)}{2}=(n-1)(n)+n^2$$

Factor in the monomials on each side:

$$\frac{4n^2-2n}{2}=n^2-n+n^2$$

Simplify both sides for the last time:

$$2n^2-n=2n^2-n$$

This method takes a little longer but I feel it's more intuitive and solid.

Comment: The question is specifically about combinatoric proofs, and this is algebraic rather than combinatoric.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question specifically but, at least for myself, was a helpful supplement to the concepts.